# Xcode 4.2.1 is not ignoring ignored files (workspace, breakpoints) when making svn commit

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, xcode4

I'm using Lion and Xcode 4.2.1 and currently, every time I'm making commit, Xcode asks me to commit my project workspace settings (workspace, breakpoints), and it's very annoying because I don't need to commit that and I don't' want to see them. I tried to ignore those files by selecting "ignore" command but that doesn't seem to work - they still appear in the commit list.

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to CVS like me I recommend using SmartCVS for Mac. Before you do anything copy your project to another folder so you have a backup in case something goes wrong while you do this. If you want to ignore a file left click on it and choose Ignore from the context menu. Afterwards you can go to the folder where the file is situated and you should see file .cvsignore This file is hidden so make sure you can see hidden files.

If Ignore option is grayed out than you have already added this file and commited it. This means the CVS is already tracking your file. First you should remove the file from CVS, then revert it and then you should be able to Ignore it.

Answer (score -1):

You can install these files to ignore. Then it will not show, but did not change the file will be stored in SVN. Are you saying that the file added to the ignorance, but still see it in the list of changes you have done something wrong.

You can not hide the file so that it could not be seen, and continued to record changes in SVN.

You need to set up an alias in bash console, which you will filter the output files and remove unnecessary. I don't know how to do that, only know that can help you.